# Click event from button inside popup is not working

Tags: jquery, .net, popupwindow

I am creating a popup window using jQuery in my ASP.Net application. The popup is opening on button click. I have written following code to open the popup.

html code:

```
        <%-- Popup --%>
        <div id="modal_dialog" class="PopupStyle" style="display: none;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        <label class="control-label">Photo</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
                            ID="regexValidateImageFil" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
                            ErrorMessage="Only file types with jpg, png, gif are allowed."
                            ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-~ :\\])+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.bmp|.BMP|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG|.pdf)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        <label class="control-label">File Type</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUpFileType" runat="server" class="form-control" Width="400px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        <label class="control-label">Note</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="150" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div style="padding: 10px">
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveUpoad" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text=" Upload File " OnClick="btnSaveUpoad_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*=btnUpoad]").on("click", function () {
            debugger;
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog({ width: 520 });

            $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                title: "Upload Files",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see there is a button in my the html, i.e.,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveUpoad" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text=" Upload File " OnClick="btnSaveUpoad_Click" />
```

But the click event (from button inside popup i.e., btnSaveUpoad) is not calling the corresponding function written in the .cs file.

Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Partha

Comment: Not calling what function? What does the button have to do with the datepicker code? Not at all clear what problem is

Comment: Should also be `OnClick="btnSaveUpoad_Click()"` to invoke the function. Note missing `()`

Comment: I have a button inside my popup, but when I click on the button the click event written in .cs file is not calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this for your solution:
$(document).on("click", "[id*=btnUpoad]",function () {
```

**This may work for you.**

**jQuery behaves differently**
As you assign any button event directly with class then it will only work with the current class which is in DOM but if suppose new Document content added in DOM and you want to fire a click event on that newly added DOM element. Then you have to go with this

```
   *For current DOM 
    jQuery(".abc").click(function(){});*

    *For dynamic dom element 
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".abc", function(){});*
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick isn't calling the function because you are missing `()` to invoke it

Change

```
OnClick="btnSaveUpoad_Click"
```

To

```
OnClick="btnSaveUpoad_Click()"
```

Comment: Getting error: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'FileCreationForm.btnSaveUpoad_Click(object, EventArgs)'

Answer (score 0):

use Jquery on click event to bind. Also I would recommend you to create button Events f once the model is fully loaded.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
})
```

to see of modal is created and show. you can add the events to be intialized within the below function

```
$( "#code" ).on('shown', function(){
    alert("I want this to appear after the modal has opened!");
});
```